# Python how to create a dictionary based on shared pattern

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to group within the same key the substring of an item.

here is my list:

```
list_key = ['I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1b2a', 'I2a1a2', 'I2a1b1a1a1b1a']
```

for example here, 'I2a1a2' is present in 'I2a1a2a' and in 'I2a1a2a1a2'. Based on that, I would like to create a dictionary where the key is the motif and the values the list of the strings where the key is found.

expected output:

```
dic_branches = {'I2a1a2':['I2a1a2','I2a1a2a','I2a1a2a1a2'],'I2a1b1a1a1b1a':[''],'I2a1b2a':['']}
```

my code :

```
for i in range(len(list_key)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(list_key)):
        diff_length = abs(len(list_key[i])-len(list_key[j]))
        if list_key[i] == list_key[j][:-diff_length]:
            print (list_key[i],list_key[j])
        else:
            print (list_key[j])
```

Regarding my code, with the `print (list_key[i],list_key[j])`, I can target 'I2a1a2','I2a1a2a','I2a1a2a1a2' but with duplicate! I suppose there is a correct way to get the expected output!
Any suggestion?
Many thanks

Comment: "expected output:" I can't understand the underlying logic. Please explain, step by step, how you would compute this by hand. For example, what is the **rule that tells you** that `'I2a1a2'` should be a key of the output dictionary, and why the value should be a list containing `['I2a1a2','I2a1a2a','I2a1a2a1a2']`? Why shouldn't it contain anything else?

Comment: Is LCS (longest common substring) what you are looking for? If so there are tons of implementations of that right of the shelf.

Comment: "Regarding my code, I am not going in the easiest way to achieve that!" **If it reliably gets the right answer**, then you need a much more precise question in order for it to be valid on Stack Overflow. We do not do code review - there is a separate [codereview.se] for that. For example, is it too slow, or use too much memory?

Comment: Hi Karl Knechtel, many thanks for your comment. Sorry and I tried to clarify my question! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use  `in`

This ploy can be used with dictionary and list comprehensions for efficiency:

```py
keys = ['I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1b2a', 'I2a1a2', 'I2a1b1a1a1b1a']

output = {
    key: [big_key for big_key in keys if key in big_key]
    for key in keys
}

print(output)
```

For a pretty output just so we can see easily here, you can pretty-print it.

```py
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

keys = ['I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1b2a', 'I2a1a2', 'I2a1b1a1a1b1a']

output = {
    key: [big_key for big_key in keys if big_key.startswith(key)]
    for key in keys
}

pp.pprint(output)
```

Result is as follows. It is different from your example output but you did mean to include keys that are contained, *including the same key*, didn't you?

```
{   
    'I2a1a2': ['I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2'],
    'I2a1a2a': ['I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a'],
    'I2a1a2a1a2': ['I2a1a2a1a2'],
    'I2a1b1a1a1b1a': ['I2a1b1a1a1b1a'],
    'I2a1b2a': ['I2a1b2a']
}
```

#### If you want keys to appear only *once* amongst the lists...

... then you need to remove them one-by-one, and it is best to do that from a duplicate list, so that you don't mess up your looping.

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

keys = ['I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1b2a', 'I2a1a2', 'I2a1b1a1a1b1a']

## Order the keys from shortest to longest
keys = sorted(keys, key=lambda k:len(k))

## Make a duplicate copy of keys, which we will iteratively remove items from, one by one, as we use them
unused_keys = keys[:]

output = {}
for small_key in keys:
    output[small_key] = []
    for big_key in unused_keys[:]:
        if small_key in big_key:
            unused_keys.remove(big_key)
            output[small_key].append(big_key)

pp.pprint(output)
```

This is what you get:

```
{
    'I2a1a2': ['I2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2a1a2'],
    'I2a1a2a': [],
    'I2a1a2a1a2': [],
    'I2a1b1a1a1b1a': ['I2a1b1a1a1b1a'],
    'I2a1b2a': ['I2a1b2a']
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Eureka, It looks great! However, why we still get     'I2a1a2a': ['I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a'],'I2a1a2a1a2': ['I2a1a2a1a2']? since we have 'I2a1a2': ['I2a1a2a1a2', 'I2a1a2a', 'I2a1a2']?